# How to remove quotes in a variable in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an issue in batch programming. I fetch the strings generated by consoles, then the string contains double quotes and I will save that to a variable, like,

```
"/path/compile" -o source.cpp
```

And now my problem is, how can I remove this 2 double quotes? I'm not sure how to remove that quotes in the middle of the string.

Please advise

Comment: Check out this solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804646/how-do-you-strip-quotes-out-of-an-echoed-string-in-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: check this link
set widget="a very useful item"
set widget
set widget=%widget:"=%
set widget
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964192/removing-double-quotes-from-variables-in-batch-file-creates-problems-with-cmd-en

Answer (score 9):

```
set a="hello" world
set b=%a:"=%
```

Answer (score 5):

correct syntax:

```
set "tempvar="/path/compile" -o source.cpp"
echo %tempvar%
set "tempvar=%tempvar:"=%"
echo %tempvar%
```