# Pass array as an argument from c# to batch (not a duplicate)

Tags: c#, batch-file, scripting

so I'm trying to send an array from my C# code to a batch file, on which I need to perform a for-each loop.

My C# code:

```
string MyBatchFile = {the batch file path}
int[] x = {1,2,3};
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
       Arguments = String.Format("{0}", x)
    }
};
process.StartInfo.FileName = MyBatchFile;
process.Start();
```

My batch file:

```
set array=%1
FOR %%x IN %array% DO (
echo %%x
/*Some more lines here*/
)
pause
```

This doesnt seem to work, and if I print `%array%` I get `"System.Int32[]"`. What am I doing wrong?

Note: The main goal is not to print the array, but rather to perform a few actions on each value in the array. The printing is merely an example.

EDIT: I managed to finally do it, found some workaround :)
I won't be publishing how I did it, since it's a "duplicate", isn't it?
Cheers.

Comment: That's not the C# code that gives you `"System.Int32[]"`, that's what you get if you call `Int32[].ToString()`. Anyway if you have an array you want to print as a single string, look into `string.Join()` as explained in the duplicate.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
But, as I said, I need to perform a for-each loop, not just to print the array, the print was an example (and is just a small part of the code), that is why I wrote "/*some more lines here*/" . My question remained unanswered.

Comment: Could you please remove the "duplicate" tag from this question, I believe it is misleading. @CodeCaster

Comment: It's not misleading. Your C# code does not contain an integer array. Create a [mcve]. If it does contain an integer array, see the duplicate for how to print that as a comma-separated string.

Comment: Added some changes to the code, and rephrased some parts of the question.
So now to the point - I need to perform a for-each loop on an int array from within the batch file, ***I do not need to print it***.

Comment: And now we're back to square one, and the duplicate answers your question. Your problem _is_ with printing, or rather formatting, namely formatting the int array into an argument string. It now prints the string "System.Int32". Do as the duplicate says.

Comment: But how does it help me, to format the int array into a string like in the duplicate? Can I iterate a string?

Comment: See the EDIT in the question @CodeCaster

Comment: I've removed most of my comments. I'll admit that only half of your problem is answered by the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a combination of joining strings, quoting command line arguments and parameter cleanup.

In order to build your argument string, you need to `String.Join()` your integer array into a single string:

```
new StartInfo
{
    Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\"", string.Join(" ", x));
}
```

Now `arguments` holds the string `"1 2 3"` including quotes. This makes it a single argument to your batch file.

Then in the batch file, you need to clean the argument and then you can loop over it:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Copy the argument into a variable
SET array=%1
REM Trim the quotes from the variable
SET array=%array:"=%

REM Loop over each space-separated number in the array
FOR %%A IN (%array%) DO (
    ECHO %%A
)
```

References:

- [Convert array of integers to comma-separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756565/convert-array-of-integers-to-comma-separated-string)
- [Removing double quotes from variables in batch file creates problems with CMD environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964192/removing-double-quotes-from-variables-in-batch-file-creates-problems-with-cmd-en)
- [How do you loop in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355791/how-do-you-loop-in-a-windows-batch-file)

You could also still go the comma-separated way, see [How to loop through comma separated string in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158719/how-to-loop-through-comma-separated-string-in-batch).

Comment: I was really just about to mark this question as answered, and thank you for your precious time and perhaps apologize too. But now it is marked as duplicate again. This is truly ridiculous. I won't be wasting any more time trying. Best of luck, and sorry if I offended you.

Comment: No problem, it was a nice exercise and I hope I haven't offended you as well.